# If $X + Y$ has the distribution you would expect from independence, then are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, and that $X'$ has the same distribution as $X$, and $Y'$ the same distribution of $Y$. Suppose also that $X'$ and $Y'$ are independent. Then if $X + Y$ has the same distribution as $X' + Y'$, are $X$ and $Y$ also independent?

Comment: Uncorrelated:yes. Independent:not in general. I suspect there is a brainstorm going on in order to find a counterexample. I don't think I will be the first. My brains are too slow :(.

Comment: Counterexample: Cauchy distributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the discrete variables $X,Y$ each have range $\{1,2,3,4\}$ with joint probability mass function $P(X=x,\ Y=y)=f(x,y)$ where
$$f(1,2)=f(2,4)=f(3,1)=f(4,3)=0,$$
$$f(1,3)=f(2,1)=f(3,4)=f(4,2)=\frac18,$$
$$f(1,1)=f(1,4)=f(2,2)=f(2,3)=f(3,2)=f(3,3)=f(4,1)=f(4,4)=\frac1{16}.$$
You can verify that $X$ and $Y$ have a uniform distribution on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and that $X+Y$ has the same distribution it would have if $X$ and $Y$ were independent.

Comment: Great example !

Comment: Could you share how you thought of this?

Comment: @AreaMan I decided to go for discrete uniform distributions because that seemed easiest. So I needed an $n\times n$ matrix where each row, column, and SW-NE diagonal adds up to what it's supposed to. I tried $n=4$ because it's the smallest case where I've got more variables than equations. Then a bit of trial and error to find how to make a $4\times4$ matrix with entries $0,\pm1$ (not all $0$'s of course) where each row, column, and SW-NE diagonal sums to $0.$ Finally convert that to a probability matrix.

Comment: @bof Thanks. What do you mean by converting a matrix with entries in $\{0, \pm 1\}$ into a probability matrix?

Comment: @AreaMan I just meant that I replaced $a_i$ with $(1+a_i)/16.$ Nothing profound going on, it was just easier to write $-1,0,1$than $0,\frac1{16},\frac18$ while doing my scratch work.